# Why don't the kinematic equations agree with calculating velocity one second at a time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A car is moving at a velocity of $10 \, \text{m}/\text{s}$. After point $A$ no acceleration is provided. By simple measurement, the acceleration is found to be $-1 \, \text{m}/\text{s}^2$.

Using standard equations: $$v = u + at, \; v=0, \; u = 10, $$ we arrive at $t = 10 \text{s}$.

$$S = ut + .5 at^2 = 50 \,\text{m}$$

ie- the car stops at $50\, \text{m}$ from point $A$.

However, by manual calculation, the car travels the following distance before coming to stop: $10 \, \text{m}$ at $t=0$, $9 \, \text{m}$ at $t =1$, etc since $a = -1$, the $v$ reduces by $1 \, \text{m}/\text{s}$, so on, so we get $S = 10 +9+..1 = 55 \, \text{m}$

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I would have thought this would be a duplicate of another question - I really think I've seen another one like this, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @DavidZ The title was changed.

Comment: @LDC3 yes, I edited the title of this question, but that's not relevant to what I was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is going wrong with your manual calculation is you are taking the velocity to be constant in every interval i.e., you are taking velocity to be $10m/s$ from $0$ to $1s$, $9m/s$ from $1s$ to $2s$ and so on which is incorrect. The velocity is continuously decreasing. You may calculate like this:

At $t=0,v=10m/s,a=-1m/s^2$ which means from $t=0$ to $t=1$, car has travelled a distance, $$S=10\times1+\frac{1}{2}(-1)\times 1^2$$$$=10-\frac{1}{2}$$
and the velocity has become $9m/s$ at $t=1s.$ So, from $t=1$ to $t=2$,car has travelled a distance, $$S=9\times1+\frac{1}{2}(-1)\times 1^2$$$$=9-\frac{1}{2}$$ and so on.

$$10-\frac{1}{2}+9-\frac{1}{2}+......$$$$=55-5=50$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes as answered above you are making mistake in approximating the values.
You are taking **speed** to be constant for 1 sec. interval, rather it is **changing everytime**.
Newton's equations are just based on integral method of using kinematic relations like
$$s=\int v\,dt$$
$$v=\int a\,dt$$
So either trying using integral calculus or newton's equations.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. This site features MathJax/LaTeX. It's easy to use. Click the edit button on your post to see how your equations are expressed in TeX.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. What you are getting is the error in approximating the velocity at various times. The only time that the velocity is 10 m/s is at exactly t=0 sec. The only time that the velocity is 5 m/s is at exactly t=5 sec. You would have less error if you did the average of the beginning velocity and the final velocity of the time segments. For 1 sec time segments, you would calculate the velocity being 9.5 m/s, 8.5 m/s, etc. Adding these up you get a distance of 50 m.